# Icon in OutlineButton not centered after giving parent Container a smaller width

Tags: flutter

Previously my construct looked as follows:

```
Container(
  child: OutlineButton(
    child: Icon(this.iconData),
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
    left: 2,
    right: 2,
  ),
)
```

That resulted in icon buttons like these three:

[image]

But I wanted to make them a little bit smaller, so  I added a `width` to the `Container()`:

```
Container(
  width: 50,                         // <-- new line 
  child: OutlineButton(
    child: Icon(this.iconData),
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
    left: 2,
    right: 2,
  ),
)
```

This resulted in this:

[image]

As you can see, the icons are not centered anymore. Why is that and has anybody an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Do you compulsorily have to use **OutlineButton**?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi No, absolutly not. But found no other short way to achieve such a Button (Icon and rounded border).

Comment: There is constructor widget named alignment in Container widget . `alignment:Alignment.center`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for this question. I was making outline button from FlatButton all this time :) I found outline button has also padding property.. If you set it to zero then you get what you were asking. Basically the OutlineButton has set some padding by default which was too big for the size you have chosen so the icon was pushed on one side. For the record if you're using Android Studio then you can easily see that if you go to Flutter Inspector => Show Debug Paint. I hope this is what you were looking for

```
Container(
        width: 50, // <-- your new line
        child: OutlineButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero, //<-- this is added
          child: Icon(Icons.person),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 2,
          right: 2,
        ),
      ),
```

Output
[image]

Comment: This one is the only working idea so far! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

You can change the size with padding

```
class NewButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){

        },
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a Button, where should I add the onPressed method?

Comment: My bad, I have edited it...I wrapped the container in a GestureDetector giving you the ability to use the **onTap** same as **onPressed**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe you should use FlatButton. I made for you with rounded borders, just edit some colors :)

```
FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange, width: 1)),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16), // Or whatever you want :)
      child: Icon(this.iconData),
    ),
  );
```

And you can try Center() widget with you icon.

Comment: Where is the width? If I just replace the OutlineButton and adjust the width with the parent Container, the result is the same in my case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
       alignment: Alignment.center, //Use alignment to place your child widget at any positioned as you want.
       width: 50,                    // <-- new line 
       child: OutlineButton(
         child: Icon(Icons.edit), 
         onPressed: () {},
       ),
       // padding: EdgeInsets.only(
       //   left: 2,
       //   right: 2,
       // ),
     ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my case for any reasons :(

Comment: Have you commented padding line of Container. it should work.

Comment: Yes, but I need this ;)